# How do I write a rewrite rule to htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect any *www.mysite.com/anything/anything* OR *www.mysite.com/anything* AND EXCLUDE *www.mysite.com/app*

TO *www.mysite.com/app*

Of course I want to exclude is optional. It would just be an extra redirect which would take extra time I suppose, it would be nice to have it excluded though.

I found these basic examples http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html and have done this:

```
RewriteRule ^*/*/$ /app
RewriteRule ^*/$ /app
```

but it doesn't work plus I still don't know how to exclude /app

Help please?

**UPDATE**

I think .* stands for 0 or more dots in regular expressions, my examples are completely wrong, I need *anything syntax* instead of the dot you used in your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /app [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ app/ [L]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't exclude the right path. But try it first.

Comment: .* is of course a regular expression, sorry about that. \.* is for points .* is for everything. 

Taken from: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/notes-last
The L flag will tell Apache to stop processing the rewrite rules for that request. Now what is often unrealised is that it now makes a new request for the new, rewritten filename and begin processing the rewrite rules again.

So it's probably unecessary for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(?!app/).*$ app [L,NC]
```

Negative lookahead in above RewriteRule will redirect everything except a URI that starts with `/app/` to `/app`.